# Unable to save an array from POST in a variable

Tags: php, arrays, post

I need to get the value of an array passed through a form. Here is my 
*$_POST array*

```
print "<pre>";
print_r($_POST);
print "</pre>";

gives this result . . . 

Array
(
[partsToAdd] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => 9
                [1] => Colleen Hurst
                [2] => Javascript Developer
                [3] => San Francisco
                [4] => 39
                [5] => 2009/09/15
                [6] => $205,500
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => 8
                [1] => Rhona Davidson
                [2] => Integration Specialist
                [3] => Tokyo
                [4] => 55
                [5] => 2010/10/14
                [6] => $327,900
            )

    )

[ProjectNum] => 1
[OrderedBy] => name
)
```

I want to get the value of 'partsToAdd' and store it in a variable for later use. This is the method I am using to try and accomplish that.

```
$selectedParts  = htmlentities($_POST["partsToAdd"], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
$ProjectNumID   = htmlentities($_POST["ProjectNum"], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
$OrderedBy  = htmlentities($_POST["OrderedBy"], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
```

The other two work fine, and I can reference them later using that variable name. The array however, does not. When I print out $selectedParts, I get nothing - empty.

There has to be a simple solution, something I'm missing.

Thanks.

Comment: htmlentities expects a string. `$_POST['partsToAdd']` is itself an array of arrays strings. you can't pass in an array. either use array_map or loops to iterate the array and htmlentities each of those strings.

Comment: Call `htmlentities()` when you're displaying the values on a web page, not when you're storing the array.

Comment: So `htmlentities ` aside, `$selectedParts  = $_POST["partsToAdd"];` will not work. @Barmar

Comment: no. that'd work fine. that just copies the array into a new variable. that's perfectly legitimate. you just can't use that array as an argument for a function that expects a STRING.

Comment: @MarcB I don't know how I missed that.. It must have been one of the permutations I didn't try. It worked well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments:

Just change the first line from

```
$selectedParts  = htmlentities($_POST["partsToAdd"], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
```

to

```
$selectedParts  = $_POST["partsToAdd"];
```

Thanks @MarcB and @Barmar